# Why this DTD is recursive?

Tags: dtd, xml

I've been given the following DTD:

```
<!ELEMENT book (title, author+, section+)>
<!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT author (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT section (title, (p | figure | section)* )>
<!ATTLIST section
id ID #IMPLIED
difficulty CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!ELEMENT p (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT figure (title, image)>
<!ATTLIST figure
width CDATA #REQUIRED
height CDATA #REQUIRED >
<!ELEMENT image EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST image
source CDATA #REQUIRED >
```

and I've been asked:

> This DTD is recursive! How does the recursion end?

Ehm... I don't understand why is it recursive? Th only thing that seams to be recursive is the presence of `0` or more `section`(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This DTD is recursive!

I wouldn't say that the DTD is recursive; I would say that the content model for `section` is recursive because it allows zero or more child `section` elements.

> How does the recursion end?

The recursion ends, in the XML instance, when a `section` does not contain a child `section`. Since the child `section` element is not required, it's not forcing some sort of runaway recursion where you'd never get your instance to validate.

Comment: Thank you. It's the same thing I thought!